# Ruby On Rails Installation Mac OS X Bundler GemFileNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Mac OS X Sierra and following [Daniel's Setup Article](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html) to install Ruby on Rails. All goes well until I get try to confirm the Rails version, I get errors saying it can't locate several files. Here's a screenshot of the console output for the last couple of steps:

[image: Rails Installation Console Output]

After the first attempt, I imploded rvm, removed all traces from .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .profile, and started from the beginning. I hit the same issue at the same point in the process. If any further information would be useful, please let me know and I'll be glad to modify. Just in case it has something to do with $PATH, I'll put the echo $PATH output below:

/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@rails5.1/bin:/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/bin:/Users/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/Users/john/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/Users/john/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

[edit] Not having had any replies and having spent an entire day trying to get it running locally, I decided to try an online environment with cloud9. I was up and running on cloud9 in 15 minutes without any issues, and that includes creating the account. I would still like to know if anyone has any ideas about the rvm local version, so I'll leave the question for now. [/edit]

Comment: I know this might not be the best suggestion but you might want to try rbenv.  I've had better luck with that than rvm.

Comment: OK thanks, I may do that if I have to.